# Android: "nowrap" in Spannable in TextView

Tags: android, textview, nowrap, spannable

Is it possible to have a spannable in TextView similar to this functionality in WebView?

```
Bob McDonalds <span style="white-space: nowrap">&lt;b.mcdonalds@domain.com&gt;</span>
```

I am trying to avoid

```
|Email: Bob McDonalds <b.          |
|mcdonalds@domain.com>             |
```

I would rather

```
|Email: Bob McDonalds              |
|<b.mcdonalds@domain.com>          |
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use Html.fromHtml(String str) and do the same thing in textview.
hope it helps.